# Update one-to-many relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a model Product which contains a list of Specification
how can I easily update all the specifications in one-to-many relationship in Laravel 10?

```
class Product extends Model {
    //...
    public function specifications() {
        return $this->hasMany(Specification:class);
    }
}

class Specification extends Model {
    //...
}
```

and the data in the `specifications` table

```
id | product_id | title       | value
10 | 42         | old title   | old val
20 | 42         | del title   | del val
```

```
$newSpecifications = [
  [
    'id' => 10,
    'title' => 'Updated title',
    'value' => 'Updated value'
  ],
  [
    'id' => null,
    'title' => 'New title',
    'value' => 'New value'
  ]
];

$product = Product::find(42);
```

how can I create/update/delete the data in specifications table?
so, the row with id 10 will be updated, with id 20 will be deleted, and anew row will be added

in Hibernate for example we just assign new value to the collection and save the entity, and it will automatically perform the operations

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    //...     
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
    private Set<Specification> specifications;
    //...
}

@Entity
public class Specification {
    //...     
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
    private Product product;
    //...
}

Product product = ...
product.setSpecifications(List.of(
  // specifications details
));

session.save(product);
```

There is `upsert` method in Laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#upserts
but it doesn't handle the deletion

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the product which you want to update it's specifications by it's id

```
$product = Product::find($productId);
```

get the specifications you want to update in array

```
$updatedSpecifications = [
        ['title' => 'New Spec 1', 'value' => 'Value 1'],
        ['title' => 'New Spec 2', 'value' => 'Value 2'],
        // Add more specifications as needed
    ];
```

Use the update method on the relationship to update all specifications

```
$product->specifications()->updateMany($updatedSpecifications);
```

Comment: I need also to create new specifications and to delete unused

Comment: you can add the id's to be overwritten in the specifications array   and delete the unused                                                                                          $updatedSpecifications = [
    ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'New Spec 1', 'value' => 'Value 1'],
    ['id' => 2, 'title' => 'New Spec 2', 'value' => 'Value 2'],
    // Add more specifications as needed
];

Answer (score 0):

As you have the `$product` model which can have many specifications and you are using the `hasMany` relation. you can create/update/delete specification like this

1. How to create specification

```php
$product = Product::find(42);
$product->specifications()->create([
    'title' => 'New title',
    'value' => 'New value'
]);
```

2. How to update specification

```php
$product = Product::find(42);
$product->specifications()->find(10)->update([
    'title' => 'Updated title',
    'value' => 'Updated value'
]);
```

3. How to delete specification

```php
$product = Product::find(42);
$product->specifications()->find(20)->delete();
```

Comment: These are to many manipulations comparing to Hibernate, just to update and save, the specifications array can contains 20-30 elements, or even more

Comment: Do you want to perform that action in a single operation? You don't have to repeat `$product = Product::find(42)`

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a single operation, something like upsert
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#upserts

Comment: `upsert` only allows to create model which doesn't exist or update if it exists. but there is not way to create/update/delete model in a single model as each action you perform doesn't return a instance to the relation object if that was the case you could chain multiple update to the same relation

Comment: Here is an example if you do `$product->specifications()->find(41)->update()` as you call update on the item which was find from the relation `specifications` it will return a laravel `Collection` object not the relation that why it's not possible to chain multiple action on the relation

Answer (score -1):

There are three ways to update one-to-many relationship in Laravel:

```
1- // Retrieve the user you want to update
$user = User::find($userId);

// Update child records (posts)
foreach ($user->posts as $post) {
    // Update the post's attributes
    $post->title = 'New Title';
    $post->content = 'Updated Content';
    $post->save(); // Save the updated post
}

2- // Alternatively, you can use the saveMany method to update multiple posts at once
$newPostsData = [
    ['title' => 'New Title 1', 'content' => 'Updated Content 1'],
    ['title' => 'New Title 2', 'content' => 'Updated Content 2'],
];

$user->posts()->saveMany($newPostsData);

3- // You can also use the create method to create and associate new posts
$newPost = $user->posts()->create([
    'title' => 'New Title',
    'content' => 'Updated Content',
]);
```

Comment: Create and update can be handled by upsert method https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#upserts , but it doesn't handle the deletion, same as in your response